# Why the function app stop working suddenly?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am having a function app which is running on consumption plan (Y1). as you can see below screen shots the execution count was suddenly drop to 0 for some time (~30min). in that time the app getting the requests as well. but giving 4xx errors.

[image]

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Thats an interesting little period you have in your graph there.  Is it all http 4xx if you drill into app insight logs can see if its 400's or 404s by any chance.  I have a feeling its because the client calling the function app was passing bad data etc resulting in a 400 Bad Request during that period.

If its something with the core function app you will get a 502 or a 500, was there a deployment or code change during that period that could have triggered client side bad requests.